# Ruby - HornetsEye

Tags: ruby

I am compiling HornetsEye on Linux Mint 9. And I think it should be successful. When I tried 'require 'hornetseye'' in irb, I got the following message.

```
RuntimeError: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i486-linux/RMagick2.so: This installation of RMagick was configured with ImageMagick 6.5.5 but ImageMagick 6.5.7-8 is in use.

    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/RMagick.rb:11
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from (eval):0
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:168
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like since the version of `RMagick` was built on your system, the `ImageMagick` libraries on which it depends has been refreshed to a newer version (e.g. a system update). RMagick is detecting that this run-time does not match the build version. I'd reinstall RMagick to make them compatible again. See [here](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install2-linux.html)

Comment: Instead of downgrading RMagick, is it possible to bring HornetsEye updated?

Comment: I don't think you need to down- or upgrade anything. Just reinstall RMagick (i.e. it will be relinked against your system installed ImageMagick libraries)